# List privilegedRoles using Azure app/service principal

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to request the ["List privilegedRoles" resource](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/api/privilegedrole_list) using an app created in Azure's Active Directory.

I've given it all the Application permissions AND Delegated permissions in the Graph API app, to no avail.

The response is always:

```
"error": {
  "code": "UnknownError",
  "message": "{\"message\":\"An error has occurred.\"}",
  "innerError": {
    "request-id": "3e1bb5cf-2d2e-402f-8648-27193b28510a",
    "date": "2018-06-06T14:26:02"
  }
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated

**UPDATE 1:**
A full reproduction of the issue -

- A V2 app with delegated permission "Directory.AccessAsUser.All" (and no application permissions), redirect url of http://localhost/myapp/permissions

step 1: admin consent

open browser at:
https://login.microsoftonline.com/MY-TENANT-ID/adminconsent?client_id=MY_APP_ID&state=12345&redirect_uri=http://localhost/myapp/permissions

and grant consent by an admin to the requested permission(s)

see successful redirect to:
http://localhost/myapp/permissions?admin_consent=True&tenant=MY_TENANT_ID&state=12345

step 2: get token

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -d 'client_id=MY_APP_ID&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2F.default&client_secret=MY-APP-SECRET&grant_type=client_credentials' 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/MY_TENANT_ID/oauth2/v2.0/token'
```

get reply like:

```
{
    "token_type": "Bearer",
    "expires_in": 3599,
    "ext_expires_in": 0,
    "access_token": "SOME-VERY-LONG-TOKEN"
}
```

step 3: attempt to get the resource

```
curl -X GET -H "Authorization: Bearer SOME-VERY-LONG-TOKEN" 'https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/privilegedRoles'
```

**ERROR:**

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "UnknownError",
    "message": "{\"message\":\"An error has occurred.\"}",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "cc9c950c-369c-4fb5-8ec4-eb4048e32a5d",
      "date": "2018-06-10T09:09:57"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you please provide an example of the code your using and the bearer token you're sending to the API?

Comment: @MarcLaFleur its a little complicated as this is spread across multiple java classes.

I am using this same method to successfully fetch the users and groups from the graph APIs though, so I think the issue is not there.

As I mentioned, the token is created via a service principal/app using the triplet of (tenant id, app id, secret).

Comment: Without seeing some code or the token, it's just a guessing game. Since a token cannot hold _both_ App and Delegated, understanding how you're getting that token will explain a lot. Check out this article for a deeper explanation:https://massivescale.com/application-vs-delegated-scopes/

Comment: @MarcLaFleur see my update with sample reproduction. only a delegated permission is present.

Comment: Take a look at the article I linked to. You're using Client Credentials which means you're _not_ using Delegated permissions. The article I linked to explains how these scopes work.

Answer (score 0):

You can only use delegated permission for calling MSGraph PIM Api's.
Basically, you will need to do the following setup:

1. Create a native AAD application
2. Grant it Read and write privileged access to Azure AD permission and make sure the admin consents to it
3. Call MSGraph PIM Api's using this app with delegated token.

For more details, see https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/anujchaudhary/2018/06/07/powershell-sample-for-privileged-identity-management-pim-for-azure-ad-roles/

Comment: looks like you are not using delegated permissions. can you try the step by step instructions provided in the sample I provided

Comment: As I am attempting to use the REST API, the PowerShell actions are opaque - the action `$authContext.AcquireToken("https://graph.microsoft.com",$ClientID,$redirectUri,[Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.PromptBehavior]::Always)` does not tell me which authn. APIs to use to acquire the code & token.
Do you happen to know which ones?
I believe that at this point I attempted all the combinations of both v1 and v2 auth. endpoints :/

Comment: PowerShell is just the application which is invoked (can be UX, etc.). If you look at the code, its calling the REST API. $authContext.AcquireToken prompts the user for credentials to acquire a token using ADAL for .Net. You can find ADAL for different platforms here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-authentication-libraries.